# Two equivalent functions give two different indefinite integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I consider the following indefinite integral

$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{P^2 s^{-2p} +1}} ds$

for $p,P>0$. By multiplying the integrand with $\frac{s^p}{s^p}$ this can be written as

$\int \frac{s^p}{\sqrt{P^2 +s^{2p}}} ds$

But Mathematica gives for those two integrals two different results:

```
In[20]:= Integrate[1/Sqrt[P^2*s^(-2 p) + 1], s, 
 Assumptions -> {s > 0, p > 0, P > 0, Element[s, Reals], 
   Element[p, Reals]}]

Out[20]= s Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -(1/(2 p)), 
  1 - 1/(2 p), -P^2 s^(-2 p)]

In[19]:= Integrate[s^p/Sqrt[P^2 + s^(2 p)], s, 
 Assumptions -> {s > 0, p > 0, P > 0, Element[s, Reals], 
   Element[p, Reals]}]

Out[19]= (s^(1 + p) Sqrt[1 + s^(2 p)/P^2]
  Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (1 + p)/(2 p), 
  1/2 (3 + 1/p), -(s^(2 p)/P^2)])/((1 + p) Sqrt[P^2 + s^(2 p)])
```

Since I am no expert for Hypergeometric functions, I plotted both results for $p,P=1$. The results give me the impression, that something goes definitely wrong here. Did I make some stupid mistake?

```
In[21]:= Plot[s Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -(1/(2 p)), 
    1 - 1/(2 p), -P^2 s^(-2 p)] /. {p -> 1, P -> 1}, {s, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
In[22]:= Plot[(s^(1 + p) Sqrt[1 + s^(2 p)/P^2]
    Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (1 + p)/(2 p), 
    1/2 (3 + 1/p), -(s^(2 p)/P^2)])/((1 + p) Sqrt[
   P^2 + s^(2 p)]) /. {p -> 1, P -> 1}, {s, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: "multiplying the integrand with s^p/s^p this can be written as"  You can't just pull something out of the integral like this. SQRT(x^2) = x only when x>=0. So in your case, you have assumed `s^p` is positive. I do not know if this is the case always or not since I did not look at all your code carefully. Just something to look at .  is `s^p` always positive over the integration domain? If not, they both integrands are not the same.

Comment: Also, remember that these are indefinite integrals, defined only up to a constant.  `Plot[Evaluate[{%1 - 1, %2} /. {p -> 1, P -> 1}], {s, -1, 1}]` shows that the two are identical for `s > 0`.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it.

Comment: @bbgodfrey It's even worse. With branch-cuts, it's possible for them to differ by up to a piecewise constant. This is always a surprise for people the first time they learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever plotted both functions? What do you see?

```
f1 = 1/Sqrt[pp^2*s^(-2 p) + 1]
f2 = s^p/Sqrt[pp^2 + s^(2 p)]
Plot[f1 /. {p -> 1, pp -> 1}, {s, -1, 1}]
Plot[f2 /. {p -> 1, pp -> 1}, {s, -1, 1}]
```